# Is this true $f(n)+\mathcal O(f(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, self-learning

> Is this true $f(n)+\mathcal O(f(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$?

f(n) + {set of all functions upper bounded by f(n)} = function upper bounded by f(n) and so $\mathcal O$ follows from this.

But how lower bound is also f(n) from which we can infer $\Theta $

$f(n)+\mathcal O(f(n))  \geq ?$

In above statement in Qn, if i replace $\mathcal O $ with $\mathcal o$ then how the statement is true? kindly elaborate

Comment: If you are dealing with positive functions, then clearly $$f(n) + O(f(n)) \ge f(n)$$

Comment: sir the problem talks about only upper bound right. how can we think of lower bound here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is entirely possible that $g\in O(f)$ and $f+g\in o(f)$. Namely, with $g=-f$.

It is however true that if $g\in o(f)$, then $f+g\in \Theta(f)$. In fact, eventually $\lvert g\rvert\le \frac12\lvert f\rvert$ and therefore, eventually, $$\frac12\lvert f\rvert\le\lvert f\rvert-\lvert g\rvert\le\lvert f+g\rvert\le\lvert f\rvert+\lvert g\rvert\le\frac32\lvert f\rvert$$

Comment: sir i am a beginner. can you pls elaborate 1st statement in your answer. If g=-f, then f+g = f-f=0?

Comment: Yes, and usually $0\notin\Theta(f)$.

Comment: Yes, understood now

Comment: Sir Inequality here does the magic in proof. But if i think intuitively, given f+{set of all functions upper bounded by f} has maximum value f and min value?(can not infer any thing if i go by meaning of given functional set).